# Filter only email messages from a mailfolder using microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of emails from a shared mailbox using microsoft graph library. I can easily retrieve all of them or filter by category or sender. But I want to exclude from the result other types of items from that folder like calendar meeting requests.

I have tried filtering with `isof(microsoft.graph.message)`, but it doesn't seem supported. I also tried the following filters: `"odata.type eq '#microsoft.graph.message'"` or `OdataType eq '...'`

If I get all without any filter, I can then filter the objects from the resulted collection based on type, but I would like to not get them at all.

Can anyone please help? (I am doing this in .net but I guess it shouldn't matter if I can get the correct filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the correct query for `$filter` is `$filter=(isof('microsoft.graph.message'))` but it's not supported by the Graph API for messages.

I would suggest to use [Extended properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) and filter by the canonical property [PidTagMessageClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagmessageclass-canonical-property).

To filter `microsoft.graph.message`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String 0x001A' and contains(ep/value, 'IPM.Note'))
```

To filter `microsoft.graph.eventMessageRequest`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String 0x001A' and ep/value eq 'IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request')
```

To filter `microsoft.graph.eventMessageResponse`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String 0x001A' and ep/value eq 'IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Pos')
```